# class properties values while adding to list last value is getting in forloop in c#

Tags: c#

```
 class AgeWeightedHistorical
    {
        public DateTime ExposureDate { get; set; }
        public double ProfolioPrices { get; set; }
        public double LastPeriods { get; set; }
        public double HybridWeights { get; set; }
        public double CummulativeWeights { get; set; }
    }
    private List<AgeWeightedHistorical> Data;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[] values ={1275,1254.380054,1288.972603,1292.276423, 1302.272727,1264.986911,1349.010554,1265.461347,1287.81407,1268.656716,                            1278.1875,1284.538653,1281.311881,1303.263547,1262.710843,1271.89781,1287.439024,1265.76087,1290.510949,1305.649038,1316.901408,1298.181818,1292.075893,1283.42511,1258.260394};
        DateTime[] datetime ={Convert.ToDateTime("10/02/2010"), Convert.ToDateTime("10/03/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/04/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/05/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/06/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/07/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/08/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/09/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/10/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/11/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/12/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/13/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/14/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/15/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/16/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/17/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/18/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/19/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/20/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/21/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/22/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/23/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/24/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/25/2010"),Convert.ToDateTime("10/26/2010")};
        GridView1.DataSource = Service(values, datetime);
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
private static List<AgeWeightedHistorical> Service(double[] values, DateTime[] datetime)
    {
        List<AgeWeightedHistorical> Data = new List<AgeWeightedHistorical>();
        AgeWeightedHistorical ag = new AgeWeightedHistorical();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            ag.ExposureDate = datetime[i];
            ag.ProfolioPrices = values[i];
            ag.LastPeriods = values.Length - Data.Count;
            Data.Add(ag);
        }
        return Data;
    }
```

Above code will add Prices, dates and Past Periods to Grid View. But grid view is getting same values for all rows. please help me...

Answer (score 1):

you need to move this line:

```
AgeWeightedHistorical ag = new AgeWeightedHistorical();
```

Into the loop. Otherwise will you always use the same object. So the for loop should be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    AgeWeightedHistorical ag = new AgeWeightedHistorical();
    ag.ExposureDate = datetime[i];
    ag.ProfolioPrices = values[i];
    ag.LastPeriods = values.Length - Data.Count;
    Data.Add(ag);
}
```

And you know in this case you can use `var` too. More cleaner. Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    var ag = new AgeWeightedHistorical();
    ag.ExposureDate = datetime[i];
    ag.ProfolioPrices = values[i];
    ag.LastPeriods = values.Length - Data.Count;
    Data.Add(ag);
}
```

Comment: may i know the reason of not using  AgeWeightedHistorical ag = new AgeWeightedHistorical();

Comment: @Jyothi : You can do that it is fine.. Maybe it is just a style of coding. When you declare a new you do not have to tell it twice. I personally thinks it is cleaner and more clear